# Is_valid method return false in the second time using

Tags: django, unit-testing, modelform

I write the unittest for my post function,but in the second time,It's always fail.here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    update_at = models.DateTimeField()
    post_title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    activity_address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    post_content = models.TextField()
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[('activity', 'activity', ), ('blog', 'blog')])
    post_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[('open', 'open'), ('locked', 'locked') ])
```

here is the postlib.py

```
from models import Post
from forms import PostForm
from django.utils import timezone

def create(data):
    if not data['created_at']:
        data['created_at'] = timezone.now()
    if not data['update_at']:
        data['update_at'] = timezone.now()
    post_form = PostForm(data=data)
    if post_form.is_valid():
        post = post_form.save()
    else:
        post = None
    return post
```

and the unittest code

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from Publish.forms import PostForm
from Publish.models import Post
from Publish import postlib
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PublishTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@test.com', password='abc')
        self.user = auth.authenticate(username="test", password='abc')
        self.data = {'post_author': '1',
                'post_title': 'test',
                'post_content': 'nothing',
                'activity_address': 'New York',
                'created_at': '',
                'update_at': '',
                'post_type': 'activity',
                'post_status': 'open'}

    def test_a(self):
        post = postlib.create(self.data)
        self.assertNotEqual(post, None)

    def test_b(self):
        post = postlib.create(self.data)
        self.assertNotEqual(post, None)
```

In the unittest,It always have a failure,either test_a or test_b,and the reason of failure is the form.is_valid(). the Is_valid() method will fail sometime,but I use the same data,How can it be?

PS:the post_form error is

`'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'`

Comment: Output post_form.errors (can output to console) to view what is wrong.

Comment: @sergzach oh,no!my typing error

Comment: @sergzach the error is 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.' But i use the same data,same test code,that's really weird

Comment: Probably you don't. Output the input data - for correct and incorrect results - before PostForm(data=data) and note the difference.

Comment: @sergzach the data is really same

Comment: With that error ('Select a valid choice') it's impossible. Or this is a bug of Django.